# Activating the JetPack WordPress plugin when running on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, wordpress, jetpack

I get the following error when attempting to activate the [JetPack plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/) on my WordPress instance I have running on Heroku.

Jetpack could not contact WordPress.com: register_http_request_failed. This usually means something is incorrectly configured on your web host. Operation timed out after 15000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

I found a claim that Heroku blocks this type of business-to-business traffic but couldn't find any documentation to support the claim.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I've found this issue report (https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku/issues/18) but I think is more likely a heroku issue

Comment: What errors are you seeing in Heroku logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I've found two ways to solve this:

1) The quick and dirty way (worked for me, but more a hack than a solution): Push your Web Dynos on Heroku to 2, connect JetPack, and then put the Dynos back to 1 or 0.

2) On the official Jetpack site: customize httpd.conf to allow for more concurrent connections:

http://jetpack.me/support/getting-started-with-jetpack/troubleshooting-tips/jetpack-heroku/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Have your host modify your php.ini
 function 'ini_get' get it's data from 'php.ini' so I set 'max_execution_time' there to 60

Comment: Heroku doesn't allow for editing php.ini, at least not directly. There is a possible solution. I would need to fork the [heroku-buildpack-php](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php), make changes to the included php.ini, and then [use my custom buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack). That said, I don't plan to test it due to [this open issue](https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku/issues/18).